# custom date/time format for --out-format in rsync

Tags: bash, rsync, datetime-format

According to the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf) pages, `%t` is used to output the current date and time with `--out-format`. Is there anyway to specify the format to use for the date/time?

```
$ rsync --out-format="%t" "/source" "/destination"
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/001
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/002
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/003
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/100
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/file 100
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/folder
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 1/folder/004
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 2
2019/01/19 23:12:57 | home/nacho/backup_test/source 2/006
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that no, there is not. Looking at the `rsync` source code, the `%t` format escape results in a call to the following [`timestring`](https://rsync.samba.org/doxygen/head/util_8c.html#a33) function, which you can see makes a call to `strftime()` with the hard-coded format string `"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`:

```c
char *timestring(time_t t)
{
        static char TimeBuf[200];
        struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
        char *p;

#ifdef HAVE_STRFTIME
        strftime(TimeBuf, sizeof TimeBuf - 1, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tm);
#else
        strlcpy(TimeBuf, asctime(tm), sizeof TimeBuf);
#endif

        if ((p = strchr(TimeBuf, '\n')) != NULL)
                *p = '\0';

        return TimeBuf;
}
```

Comment: Hurmph. So it's not even using system local settings. Interesting. I wonder why nobody has ever raised this and why `rsync` hasn't added the option. Seems like a basic request. Then again, maybe I'm the strange one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround (based on [Jorge Marquez solution to add the current user to rsync log](https://dev.to/jmr_code_social/rsync-10-examples-in-11-days-day-11-69)):

```
    $ rsync --archive \
            --log-file=mylog \
            --log-file-format='t:%t user:'$USER' myt:'$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M) \
            source target
```

This will result in

```
    $ cat mylog
    ...
    2021/11/26 10:53:29 [275059] t:2021/11/26 10:53:29 user:user myt:202111261053
    ...
```

Be careful with spaces. The log format options are documented in *man rsyncd.conf*.